# Headlights only working when indicating left

Tags: lights, holden

I've got a Holden Jackaroo and since a couple of weeks the headlights are a bit funny. Sometimes working, sometimes not. Today they were only working when I was indicating left and turned of when I turned the indicator of. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly a poor earth connection somewhere...

I'd start at the one closest to the headlights, and work back towards the switch - take each connection off, check it and clean it, and reconnect.